# what is the limit of the following sequence when $n \longrightarrow \infty$?

Tags: calculus

what is the limit of the sequence 
$a_n=\frac{n!(0.5)^{n-1}}{\sqrt{n}\{[(n-1)/2]!\}^2}$
when $n \longrightarrow \infty$. It seems that the right answer is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$, but I cannot figure it out. Ask for help! Thank you very much.

Comment: If $[(n-1)/2]$ means the greatest integer that is $\le (n-1)/2$, then I think your sequence doesn't converge.

Answer (score 0):

Using Stirling equivalent : 
$$a_n \sim \frac{\sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n-1}}{\sqrt{n}\sqrt{\pi (n-1)}²\left(\frac{n-1}{2e}\right)^{n-1}}$$
$$\sim \frac{\sqrt{2}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n}{\sqrt{\pi}(n-1)\left(\frac{n-1}{e}\right)^{n-1}}$$
$$\sim \frac{\sqrt{2}n^n}{\sqrt{\pi}\left(n-1\right)^{n}e}$$

Hence, $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} a_n = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{\pi}}$

Comment: But $[(n-1)/2]$ is (presumably) the greatest integer that is $\le (n-1)/2$, so this approximation is wrong when $n$ is even.

Comment: Yep, I think we should add the constraint that n is odd.